# Embedding XML in Assembly using CodeDOM

Tags: codedom

I have an XML generated at runtime. I need to embed this XML content into an assembly using CodeDOM. The XML will be accessed later from the assembly.

How can I embed XML into assembly ? Should I include the XML as EmbeddedResources in the assembly ?

Thanks

Comment: yes, that should work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for example, with the `EmbeddedResources` property. For example:

```
    Assembly a1 = typeof(MyClass).Assembly;
    System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters cp = new System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters();
    cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(a1.Location); // for example
    cp.GenerateInMemory = false;
    cp.GenerateExecutable = true;
    cp.IncludeDebugInformation = false;
    cp.CompilerOptions = "";
    cp.CompilerOptions += String.Format("/win32icon:\"{0}\"", nameOfIconFile);
    cp.CompilerOptions += " /target:winexe";
    cp.EmbeddedResources.Add(xmlFileName);

    var csharp = new Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider();
    System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults cr = csharp.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, LiteralSource);
```

The xml needs to be available in a file, in order to embed it as a resource.

Comment: how can the XML or any resource be accessed from codedom? "my.resources" keyword is not available in codedom (?)

Comment: The format string should probably be `"\"/win32icon:{0}\""`, i.e. the quotes should span the entire parameter