# Codedom compiler icon options error

Tags: c#, .net, filepath, codedom

I am working with Codedom, to compile individual Exes with custom icons.

This is the code that I am using to specify the icon file:

```
string temp;
temp = string.Format("/target:winexe /win32icon:{0}", testico);
cp.CompilerOptions = temp;
```

testico in this case is a string, specifying where the icon is located.

Now the problem is, the code above only works if there are no spaces in the file path.

Therefore, to allow filepaths with spaces, I modified the code to this:

```
string temp;
temp = string.Format("/target:winexe /win32icon:\"{0}\"", testico);
cp.CompilerOptions = temp;
```

Unfortunatly, this does not work.

Any ideas?
thanks

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5921078/266143) that syntax should be correct. Can you inspect the `temp` variable while debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
\"/win32icon:{0}\"
```

The quotes surround the entire argument